# Why does my batch file create an additional copy in current folder?

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a folder *xyz*. It has a batch file which copies files from source directory *abc* to destination directory *def*. I am using `copy` with options `/v /y`.

Copy works absolutely fine. But I notice a strange or weird issue that additionally a copy of all the files copied from source to destination are present in folder *xyz*.

I started observing this issue after a system restart and not sure if its a one time issue. But I would like to know if someone has run into this issue before and what is the possible fix?

Here is the code:

```
@if not defined ECHO_ON echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
set arg1=%1
set arg2=%2
copy /v /y !arg1! !arg2!
call :getPath !arg1!
ren !arg2!\!_NAME_EXT! !_NAME!.svg

:getPath
set _NAME=%~n1
set _NAME_EXT=%~nx1
set _LOC=%~dp1
goto:eof
endlocal
```

Please note I am using `copy` and `robocopy` command (for some other copying operation) in same .bat file.

Is this something to be worried about?

(As I wrote things worked fine until restart.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double `Copy` is because a batch script works line by line until it reaches an end of file marker or an exit instruction. A `Call` command returns back to the point just after the `Call` instruction. When it returns, there is no exit instruction or end of file marker until the bottom of your script, so the `:getPath` label is executed again.

There appears to have been absolutely no reason for `EnableDelayedExpansion` in your script, for `Set`ting any variables or for a `Call` command. I have therefore simplified it as such:

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~2"=="" Exit /B
If Not Exist "%~2\" MD "%~2" 2>Nul || Exit /B
If Exist "%~1" Copy /V /Y "%~1" "%~2\%~n1.svg"
```

*I hope it helps you out.*